# Can I say bravo to a female performer?

Tags: word-usage

Everywhere in the world after a successful performance like a live music show or theater play, you can hear audience yelling "Bravo!" to the performers regardless of their gender or number. Is this also true in Italy? Given the existence of the distinguished feminine form "brava", wouldn't it sound queer or even impolite to a female Italian performer if I say bravo to her, especially if she doesn't know that I'm not a native speaker?

Comment: I think it would help you to think of Bravo ("brah-vooh") as an English word borrowed from Italian, but still English nonetheless and thus genderless. An English speaking group of females would still expect to hear "bravo", not "brave".

Comment: If the performer is female and is one (singular), then you could simply yell *Brava!*

Comment: I am Italian born and raised in the city of Milan. I find it quite interesting how everyone seems to have an "idea" of what is proper, or improper to say after a performance regardless of what type of venue it might be. It's really silly of everyone to debate on a topic which you know absolutely nothing about. I find it to be a huge turn off when I see or hear people who seem so sure of themselves, simply because they believe to be intelligent, and more worldly cultured than most individuals. The truth is "Bravo" is just a basic common word which can be a found in any other language. By the wa

Comment: @AlfonsinaFerrari: Welcome to Italian.SE! Your post it's not an answer to the OP question, for this reason it has been converted to a comment.

Comment: Continuation of post by @AlfonsinaFerrari: By the way "Bravo" means "Good" in the language of love. I recall my father once mentioning how the people who think their intelligent, are sure to always over think everything. On the other hand to the natural genius everything is in plain site and very clear, to them it's always elementary. Do not over think everything in your daily life. Keep it simple. Life is simple. Have a great day!

Comment: One of the earliest uses of brava for a female performer, Leontyne Price is: "She won bravas after her opening trio with Radames and Amneris (a place in the opera that has not drawn applause at La Scala in years), [and ] got many more ovations as she ranged effortlessly from finespun pianissimos to brilliantly ringing fortes. " Brava, Leonessa! " cried someone in the audience, while a second voice corrected. -- The author here displays ignorance of the international character of the French intermediacy.

Comment: In Brazilian Portuguese, in terms of applause, it's 'Bravo!' for everyone, since, in this case, the word is not an adjective, but an interjection, meaning 'great', 'brilliant', as in the rest of the world... However, when the word is used as an adjective - as in 'a brave man' or 'a brave woman', we say 'bravo' or 'brava', accordingly. This, for more classical texts. In colloquial language, 'bravo' and 'brava' just mean 'angry' or 'pissed off'. Which, in fact, do not restrain snob people like me from saying 'Brava!' for female opera performers... ;-)

Comment: I wonder why this particular question elicited no less than 17 answers (as of this writing), including those later deleted as not actual answers. Admins, is this a record?

Comment: @DaG Possibly so! `;-)`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Italian, saying “Bravo!” rather then “Brava!” to a female would sound mostly funny, so you'd better use the latter, and “Bravi!” when addressing, say, a band or a performing group.

---

**Addendum**: There is a whole (short) book about the history of the Italian word *bravo* from the original meaning of “violent, bold”, derived from Latin *barbarus*, to the modern sense of “good, able”: Giuseppe Patota, *Bravo!*, il Mulino 2016.

A chapter, in particular, covers the use in the meaning mentioned in this question, confirming that *bravo!* has always agreed with the number and gender of the people so addressed. A 1826 *Dizionario e bibliografia musicale* by Peter Lichtenthal attests that:

> Si usa anche in plurale *bravi*, *brave*, allorché due o più cantanti o sonatori eseguiscono per eccellenza un Duetto, o Terzetto od altro pezzo concertato. Anche ad un Corpo intero s'indirizza talvolta, p.e. *brava orchestra* ec. Una picciola osservazione ancora. Molti hanno la strana abitudine di usare per la parola bravo tutt'altra prosodia in teatro che fuora del medesimo. Fa dunque specie a sentir gridare taluni a guisa de' Francesi *bravò* in vece di *bravo* ...

And Patota likens those Italians using the French-like pronunciation in the 19th century to those who today use Italian or Latin terms with an English pronunciation:

> A pensarci bene, gli italiani che, duecento anni or sono, pronunciavano alla francese un *bravó* che i nostri cugini d'Oltralpe avevano preso da noi fanno il paio con certi loro compatrioti d'oggi, che pronunciano all'inglese i vari *giùnior*, *mìdia* e *plàs* che l'inglese ha prelevato dal latino. Il nostro provincialismo ha radici antiche, non c'è che dire [p. 107].

Comment: Actually this is not quite correct; it depends on the context. In a classic concert, and in any educated circle, "bravo!" will be understood as it is, an international exclamation of appreciation; certainly not funny nor impolite.

Comment: I have never, ever heard “Bravo!” used by Italians to refer to a female performer or a group of more than one. Where did you hear it?

Comment: Some times. Classic music, Opera, Theatre. But didn't you already ask for a reference? You claimed that saying "bravo!" to a woman performer in a concert in Italy would always sound funny: shouldn't be you who need to prove his claim? :)

Comment: We both are claiming something: each one of us should prove it. :-) As for oral occurrences, I should be present when some Italian shout “bravo” to a woman; perhaps it will happen and I'll by happy to acknowledge it!

Comment: /brɑːˈvəʊ/ is different from /ˈbravo/ ...

Comment: "Una picciola osservazione" sarebbe "una piccola osservazione"?

Comment: Sì, @Charo, [picciolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/picciolo1) (con l'accento sulla prima “i”) è una forma antiquata o letteraria di “piccolo”.

Comment: Grazie, @DaG: non saprei dire perché, ma quando cerco "picciolo" sul Vocabolario Treccani dal mio cellulare, non mi appare l'accezione del link che hai messo nel tuo commento.

Answer (score 26):

No! To speak correct and polite Italian you would have to say:

- "Brava" to a single female performer,
- "Bravo" to a single male performer,
- "Brave" to many female performers (not even one male performer among them),
- "Bravi" to many performers if there is at least one male performer among them.

Answer (score 25):

Well, this isn't obvious, so I'll try to give you some explanations.

Like others have pointed out, you can't always say *bravo*. This is a normal adjective used to describe people, and so you'll have to use the proper ending depending on who you're talking about. The feminine singular form is *brava*. The plural forms are *bravi* and *brave* for masculine and feminine respectively.

Saying *bravo* to a woman is incorrect. Although it's not really impolite, it may make you sound as if you were mocking the performer for addressing her like a man, so don't make fun with it.

So why do all non-Italian speakers always say bravo? I can point out at least two reasons for this.

First of all, most languages treat loanwords as invariant, especially if they can't be assimilated to fit the typical inflection rules.

Furthermore, speakers of many languages will feel that they're talking about the performance rather than the performers. They may think of *bravo* as a way to say "great show!" or "good job!". In this sense, *bravo* would be used as an interjection rather than an adjective. But even when *bravo* is perceived as an adjective in the speaker's own language, declension would not apply. The best example is probably Spanish where you always say *bravo* for a good performance, despite the fact that singular endings -a/-o for adjectives are the same as in Italian.

Comment: Indeed, in portuguese we view `bravo` as referring to the performance, and hence we don't use any of the inflected forms (brava/bravos/bravas) we would use when talking about people.

Comment: In Spanish "bravo" is even listed in the dictionary as an interjection when used to express applause: https://dle.rae.es/?id=63pF2Fd . In fact, it can be used to acknowledge praise for any event (often just ironically) even if there is no subject to adjective.

Answer (score 8):

The Italian word "bravo" is used in English, French and many others. These languages take only the masculine form of the Italian adjectives and apply it to both genders. In Italian "bravo" is an adjective and its gender must agree with the noun. So for a woman, you should say "brava". In a concert, we say "brava" to a female performer, not "bravo". This is what we do in, Italy too, at a concert.

Other than that, "bravo" in Italian is something we say often to kids for something they did well and it may not be the most appropriate way of paying a compliment to someone. Personally, if speaking directly to a music performer, I would say "complimenti" or something more complex like "La tua interpretazione mi ha molto emozionato".

Comment: “Bravo” is often used when clapping hands, and cheering, and perhaps during a standing ovation. In such circumstances saying «La tua interpretazione mi ha molto emozionato» would risk to go unnoticed.

Comment: @randomatlabuser I meant they do not declense the italian word.

Comment: @DaG I said "if speaking directly"

Answer (score 6):

As clami219 said:

> No! To speak correct and polite Italian you would have to say:
>
> "Brava" to a single female performer,
>
> "Bravo" to a single male performer,
>
> "Brave" to many female performers (not even one male performer among them),
>
> "Bravi" to many performers if there is at least one male performer among them.

I just want to add that really everyone in Italy use the above, so if an Italian hear a "BRAVO!" instead of "BRAVA!" immediately think to a foreign person that doesn't know the correct way to say that, and for this it's difficult to be offended for a "BRAVO!"

Answer (score 5):

I am Italian, if you have to say it to a female you must say "brava", with the final "a"! "Bravo" is for a man. Bye!

Answer (score 4):

Se la domanda è 'Can I say bravo to a female performer?' la risposta è no, altrimenti, in Italia, saresti percepito irrispettoso del genere femminile.

---

English version

If you are asking 'Can I say bravo to a female performer?' then the answer is *no*.

Comment: What he is asking is inside the question, not only at the topic/title of the question...

Answer (score 3):

If you are speaking English, use English conjugation rules, not Italian.

In English, the verb does not change to agree with the gender of the subject it is referring to. It does in other Romance languages but not in English. "Bravo" has been assimilated from other languages, as have a vast range of other words. I don't believe reverting to Italian conjugation rules is necessary. If you say "bravo" and the performer is female, it depends if you are saying "bravo" in English. If you are saying "bravo" in Italian then there would be an issue.

Perhaps if you were an English speaker yet said "bravo" with an Italian accent that would be crossing the line. We're splitting hairs here. At the end of the day the only way to be disrespectful is to say "bravo" with Italian sounding phonetics to a female performer where they know and expect you to speak and understand Italian.

Otherwise if you are an English speaker and pronounce "bravo" with English phonetics you aren't saying anything wrong because that word is recognized as an English word. It is in English dictionaries. As are other words like ballet, lingerie, cuisine, bureau, cafe. They may have come from other languages but they are fully fledged official words of the English language and are to be pronounced with English phonetics when spoken and obey English grammar rules. The fact that "bravo" also appears in Italian and can change form depending on usage is interesting trivia but that is as far as it should go.

Answer (score 2):

short answer: NO!

long answer: you should use either bravO or bravA or bravE or bravI, it depends on the gender and the number of persons:

- single male person: bravO
- single female person: bravA
- many male persons: bravI
- many female persons: bravE
- many male and female persons: bravI

Answer (score 1):

Premise: "Bravo", as an exclamation (hence indeclinable) came into use in French, English and other European languages from the (declinable) Italian adjective through the Italian Opera,  since around the half of 18° century  (there has been a little issue of priority about it: yet it seems the term is documented in French since 1738, while in English it dates 1761. The use in German is only documented since 1854).

In Italian , while of course  "bravo" is a declinable adjective, and should be used as such, the artistic and theatre jargon  may  borrow, and does, the French- English term, so it is perfectly correct and polite (yet not very common) to express appreciation to a female performer yelling "bravo" , or  writing it in an art review, especially in a context of classic music and opera. In this case it would be understood as a foreign  term, and not Italian, though.

Comment: I never found a use of “bravo” for a female performer in Italian. Could you please provide some text where this happens?

Comment: As I said, the exclamation "bravo"  can be used and understood *in the proper context* in Italy as it is, namely *an international term of appreciation and admiration*, both in written and spoken language. 

Already googling between quotation marks "un bravo alla" (alle /agli /ai /per la /per le /per i) will provide some hundreds of examples of this use in Italian.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean in the written case (“un bravo a XXX”), but I still find it quite funny that an Italian would shout “bravo” to, say, Angela Hewitt.

Comment: Maybe... Actually what is really funny is this controversy ;)

Comment: Indeed... Bravo to us, if we amused someone. :-)

Comment: I completely agree with you @PietroMajer. However, I would add that you should congratulate with the person preferably by using the English accent - I can imagine the scene where you say "Bràvo" to a female friend of yours :)

Comment: i'm not sure you can

Answer (score 1):

**Can** you say *bravo* to a female performer? Yes.

**Should** you say *bravo* to a female performer? No. As you observed, it might be perceived as queer or even mocking/disrespectful, even if non-native speakers can get a free pass.

---

The correct form **in Italian** is "brava" ("brave" for a plurality of females, "bravo" for a male, "bravi" for the mixed case).

That said, when you say *bravo* to a female performer, this may fall in two categories:

- you are clearly an Italian, or can be mistaken for Italian, i.e., it will be expected of you that you use the proper Italian form - which you **didn't**. People will either re-evaluate you as non-Italian and point out to you with a smile that you should have said *brava*, assume that you're using the English invariant form (see below) and say nothing, or politely rebuke you by congratulating for your otherwise flawless Italian (it might also be a genuine congratulation, though); **or they will assume that you're mocking the performer** or accusing her of something (in this case, however farfetched, it might be of being a closet lesbian, of taking male hormones - it may happen at a sporting event -, or even to be a transvestite).
- you are clearly *not* an Italian: your appearance, accent, or context (e.g. in a group of English persons) shows that Italian is not your native language. In that case, intelligent people will assume that you're using the English term 'bravo', which while borrowed from Italian, is invariant. This will be even more apparent if there's more than one performer, so that 'bravo' matches neither sex nor number. There's still a risk of some slow-witted person not 'getting it', but then it will be more clearly his fault.

Since you *do* know the difference, I'd go for the Italian correct form in all cases. At worst, some non-Italian speaker will politely enquire on why you don't say *bravo*, and you will be able to educate him at no loss for you, and some gain for him.

Answer (score 1):

As a classic and opera music lover, living in UK for the last 20 years, I really like the question, as it touches things I've experimented many a times.

Le'ts assume I'm at the Royal Opera House at the end of an opera. I'm part of an audience coming from all over the globe.  I'm pleased with the performance and the performance.  What do I do?

What I normally do is really shouting my appreciation with a series of "Bravo!", intermixed with "Bravi!" (in no order or preference). In reality, for a really good performance, you just want to voice your appreciation in any possible way.

And the soprano? Same: "Bravo!" (as most of the audience) and "Brava!".

Why do I do it?  I guess instinctively you want to do what everybody else is doing to maximise its effect (e.g. like clapping at the same cadence then everybody else etc.). But you also like to express yourself as you are most accustomed: there is no right or wrong (incidentally, my English wife does the same as me).

Would I do the same in Italian at the Scala or La Fenice?

Certainly not!  I would decline the adjective properly and exclusively.

On the other hand, when I speak in Italian I say Parigi, but I say Paris (with the right pronunciation) in English or French.

Answer (score 0):

Even commentators Mary Jo Heath and Siff on the NY Metropolitan Opera matinee website use brava, to single female singers and bravi (plural masculine) to males and mixed male-female groups. This is a recent development -- and an aberration. Centuries ago bravo was borrowed by the French from Italian and is used in France and thence everywhere else as an invariable cry of approval FOR THE PERFORMANCE, not the PERFORMER(S). Comments to the contrary are ALL  made in neglect of Italian intonation. If you say brava to a singular female, the accent is on the first syllable and the meaning is 'good girl, nice' girl', not 'hooray'. In ITALY  and FRANCE the opera house bravo should be yelled with accent on the final syllable and it's invariable. It's a FRENCH  cry of approval that has gone international. Research it yourself on Google books and Amazon. Citations from the earlier 1900s and before are of the kind "bravo, Signora!".

Comment: This is true, but in Italian concert halls and opera houses it is very common to hear the declined form (and it would be surprising if it were not so), and the question was precisely about those.

Comment: I agree with @DenisNardin: I believe the question is about the normal Italian use rather than about a hypothetical Italian-to-French-to-Italian ideal norm.

Answer (score 0):

#### Warning: there's a risk to be misunderstood !

Despite the amount of answers I've not seen this risk emphasized (see below).
I see at least three keys to answer to your questions: grammar, opportunity and education.

**Grammar.** It's quite simple, as stressed elsewhere: in Italian you should use *brav**a*** for a woman, *brav**e*** for more than one, *brav**o*** for a man, *brav**i*** for more than one or for male(s) and female(s) together.

**Opportunity.** Italian is a sharp tool, if you want. From here the possibility to be **misunderstood**.
Since *brav**o*** should referer to one single male, **you can use to address specifically your compliment to one element of a group**. After all, not all the troupes are composed with artists of the same level, neither in each performance the same artist gives his/her best.
Let's do a practical example: at one point one tenor and two sopranos enter together on the stage.

- If you say *brav**o*** you may want to address your compliment only to him, highlighting his performance over the sopranos ones.
- If you say *brav**e*** the opposite, you may want to address your compliment only to the sopranos.
- If you say *brav**a*** you want to emphasize one of the sopranos on the other two artists (which one is a little more tricky to understand...).
- Moreover you may see sometimes the male artist to step back and push forward the female ones

  - Especially when the male is well known actor and the females are young you may listen *brav**o*** to highlight the attempt to promote the young ones
  - You may again listen *brav**e***  (or *brav**i***) to state the intention to make no difference (between) among the artists.

**Education.** Last but not least, **a compliment is always a compliment**.
It doesn't really matter if you say *bravo*, *bravò*, *bra-voh*, *prafo*, *blavo* or whatever. So if it is clear you are not an Italian native speaker, you will not reasonably offend anyone, and your effort will be appreciated. In this case the worst (pronunciation) the better, but since you know the differences you can choose the proper tool.

**Last note, how it sounds.** This depends on the mood, education, sensibility of those who listen. Over the time (but out of Italy) I alternatively found it queer, funny or weird, but I finish to be used to.  So an artist who travels or that performs for a non Italian public is reasonably ready to understand the compliment and not to misunderstand you... but for the public itself it depends, case by case.

Answer (score -1):

It would be grammatically correct in Italian to say "bravo, soprano", since "soprano" is a masculine noun.

Likewise, it would also be possible to say "bravo" to a group of people, if you are addressing an ensemble rather than its individual members, e.g. "bravo, quartetto".

Adjective declension is concerned with the grammatical number and gender of the associated noun, not necessarily with natural genders or actual head counts.

Comment: Just to try to explain the down-vote (not mine). It is grammatically correct in Italian to say, for example, "quello e' un bravo soprano" but not if you talk directly to the person. Directly you say _bravo_ or _brava_, because you are not speaking to the role or to the type of voice.   Moreover I never listen "bravo quartetto", something similar only in some foreign film where they do some kind parody for an Italian character. You may say "In quel quartetto sono bravi" o "e' un bel quartetto"  o  "e' un buon quartetto".