# How do you say "Good job!" in Italian?

Tags: idioms, english-comparison

I believe it is NOT “Buon lavoro” because an Italian person online expressed that this was to wish someone a good day at work.

So - what do teachers say to students to let them know they've done something well?

Comment: "this was to wish someone a good day at work." Not only that. For example a teacher could give an assignment to his students and say *Buon lavoro* to wish them a good work on the assignment. The term *lavoro* (work) is quite broad in that context. Any kind of activity could be included, not just the job.

Comment: My Italian teacher has always said "Bravo"/"Brava".

Answer (score 29):

*Ben fatto*:

is a useful expression used to indicate that you are satisfied with a job/ task which have been done well.

Comment: Yes. Lower-case _f_ though.

Answer (score 23):

[*Bravo* or *Brava*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/bravo/forced) means "Good job!".  In English, it's often used as an [exclamation in the theatre](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1880/730), but it doesn't have to be an exclamation, nor is it restricted to the theatre context.

Answer (score 14):

Teachers say 'Ottimo!' or 'Eccellente!' or 'Ottimo lavoro!' or 'Lavoro eccellente!', but they also say 'Buon lavoro!' when a job is a 'Good job!'

Comment: "Ottimo lavoro" is spot on, while I never heard "buon lavoro" as a compliment (it's used as a wish, instead).

Comment: You can answer to the direct question "Come e' quel lavoro?" with a simple "Buono", but you will never listen "Buon Lavoro" as a *dry* compliment. I mean you can listen "Hai fatto un buon lavoro" in the long form, but not "Buon lavoro!" because the last one is a wish as "Buon Natale!" or "Buon Anno!". You can often listen, instead, `"Bel lavoro!"` and you can deduce that Italian people (language) feel really close the concept of goodness and beauty `:-)`.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to the other excellent answers: a simple translation as

> Bel lavoro!

is also very common. So, *good* becomes *beautiful/nice* in the translation.

On the other hand, *"buon lavoro!"*  is used as an encouragement to someone who has to perform a task and you want to with her success.

Answer (score 10):

A common Italian expression is "Ben Fatto," or "well done." Here, the emphasis is on the adjectival modifier, "ben."

Other expressions are "Bravo," "eccellente," or "ottimo," which are also adjectives.

"Bel lavoro" is used, but is less common, because it would put the emphasis on "job," rather than "well" or "good."

Comment: "Buon lavoro" si usa però non come forma di apprezzamento, ma di incoraggiamento per un lavoro che si deve ancora svolgere, augurando che venga ben svolto.

Comment: @Martina: OK, changed it to "bel lavoro" at your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

*Bravo/Brava* doesn't mean "Good job", it's more stating a personal opinion about a person who did a good job, so "brava/bravo, because of the way the job was completed".

The best way to translate "good job" in Italian is, imho, *ben fatto*: it sounds like "properly done", so stating something related to the way the task was completed.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent for "Good Job" is Bravo or Brava, depending on who you're talking to. And you could simply emphasise the same by making that Bravissimo or Bravissima.

Then there are many other words, Ottimo (Excellent), Ben fatto (You did well) and a few others. Easiest to use is Bravo.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the closest Italian translation of "Good job!" is "hai fatto un buon/ottimo lavoro"

Answer (score 6):

I think that the best is "Ottimo lavoro!"... I always use this (I'm Italian).

Comment: Maybe "Bel lavoro!" is a better translation